# Do we merge the various company forms questions?

Tags: support

The following questions come up rather a lot:

1. [Sole proprietorship vs LLC](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4159/sole-proprietorship-vs-llc/)
2. [What are the benefits and downsides to an LLC vs. Sole Proprietorship vs. Individiual?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/what-are-the-benefits-and-downsides-to-an-llc-vs-sole-proprietorship-vs-individ)
3. [Sole proprietorship or LLC?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/sole-proprietorship-or-llc)

Is there any mechanism to merge them?  Although, I've no idea what happens to answers that have been accepted, since each of these questions has one.

[Edit: corrected link]

Answer (score 3):

Your #1 and #3 above are the same question.  (Did you mis-link one?)  With what remains, I wouldn't necessarily merge .. while "Sole proprietorship vs LLC" is a general *title*, the first question, in the body detail, actually asks about **tax benefits** *specifically*.  The title of the question could be edited to make it clear the question is about the tax benefits.

Part of the problem here is that people sometimes choose short, general/high-level titles for their questions, e.g. "X vs. Y"... whereas, question titles can and should be complete sentences containing relevant keywords (e.g. "What are the tax benefits of X vs. Y")

Comment: So the trick is to edit the question titles?

Comment: @turu In this case, yes.  I've gone ahead and changed the title of that first question.  Also, a few pointers:  If you think a question is a duplicate, post a comment to the question itself stating that with a link.  If you *know* a question is a duplicate, feel free to cast a vote to close with that reason (and post a link in a comment).

Comment: @George - don't duplicate close votes automatically post a comment?

Comment: @just Hmm...we *were* doing them manually, but now that you mention it I do remember seeing that note on closed duplicates recently. /redface When did they add that?

Comment: On *closed* duplicates, yes, the question body is modified to point to the dupe... but *before* something is closed as a duplicate, a comment to a potential duplicate does help the community vote in favor of closure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, questions can be merged.  It *may* be appropriate for questions 2 & 3.  What does everyone else think about that?

Where there are multiple accepted answers,  the accepted answer of the merge target remains the accepted answer.  Generally speaking, the merge target should be chosen on the merits of the question.  Where two questions are of equal quality, the older question should be the target of the merge.  Exceptions should be noted in a comment to the question, as should the implications of the merge.  This is important in order to not alienate members of the community by futzing with the questions.

Continuing on that topic, care should be taken with decisions to merge questions.  I know I feel a strong sense of ownership to my answers (and the few questions I ask).  However, we must also keep in mind that the point of SE sites is to have good questions and answers for now and the future.  Having useful answers split across multiple questions hinders the goal of having good reference material on these sites.

Along these lines we should not worry too much about losing 15 rep points for accepted answers losing that status due to a merge.  Overall, it is a small amount of rep and usually less then the rep from upvotes.  A merged question should benefit from increased visibility, though -- of course -- there could be more competition.